# How can I toggle a class on selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a fairly simple text editor (bold, italic, indent) and need to be able to toggle the class associated with the button on click. I have this code:

```
var selected = function ()
{
  var text = '';
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection();
  }
  return text;
}

$('textarea').select(function(eventObject)
{
  console.log(selected().toString());
  var selectedtext = selected().toString();
    $('#bold-button').click(function () { 
      $(selectedtext).addClass('bold-text');
    });
});
```

And I can get the selected text to print, but can't get the class added. I've seen other solutions that add the class on click to the entire textarea, but I dont need that. Any help?

Comment: You have to add class to an object not a `var`

Comment: The selected text is a value from a node type. You have to change the slected text to a DOM node first, before you can format it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `surroundContents()` like below. Before demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jwRG8/3/

```
    function surroundSelection() {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        span.style.color = "green";

        if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                range.surroundContents(span);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not supported less than IE9. And I worked on text selections before and I found them in consistent. [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6328906/1008575) is very much experienced on selections and most of the answers in SO related to Selections are given my him. He has written a plugin called `rangy`. You mat try it at https://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work within the textarea. I guess I'll have to use tag wrapping instead of actually changing the text

Answer (score 2):

Because you are selecting text directly, there is no element to add the class on. textNodes cannot have classes. Instead, try wrapping the text in an element:

```
$('textarea').select(function(eventObject) {
    console.log(selected().toString());
    var selectedtext = selected().toString();
    $(selectedtext).wrap('<span />').parent().addClass('bold-text');
})
```

Or you could just wrap it in a `b` tag, without the `class`:

```
$(selectedtext).wrap('<b/>');
```

Comment: I cant get either solution to work for me. I don't know if its me or the code.

Comment: @Nubby Check the demo I have provided in my answer.