# HTML - change style of the text in selections

Tags: javascript, html, styles, selection

Is it possible to change the stlye of the text in a selection?

```
<p onmouseup="mouseUp()">This is a text for testing the selection</p>
<script>
function mouseUp() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    alert(selection.toString());
    //can I cahnge the color of e.g. the first character of the selection?
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can access selection.extentNode.parentNode to replace selection (using jQuery append() function) with a span with proper formatting but it'll be much more complicate because a selection can span across multiple nodes (and this is just first problem you may have). It's easy to do only for a very simple scenario

Answer (score 2):

I've already had this problem, and found the following explanation and implementation useful:

http://jsfiddle.net/VRcvn/

```
function surroundSelection(element) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(element);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

(taken from: [Wrapping a selected text node with span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span))

EDIT:
to also change the style, here is a simple example

```
<p onmouseup="surroundSelection()">This is a text for testing the selection</p>
<script>

function surroundSelection() {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    span.style.color = "green";

    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap the first character in an element (`span` for example) and then apply some css or a class to that element.

Comment: This is how you wrap it: <span class="yourClass">Put your code here</span>

Comment: The code in my question provides a string (the selected text). Obviously I can create a new span element with this string; but my question is how to set the style of the actually selected text? (in the p element in my example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it works: click on the "T" and it will change to blue

```
<p onclick="mouseUp()">
    <span id="first_Letter">T</span>his is a text for testing the selection
</p>
<script>
    function mouseUp() {
        var first_L = document.getElementById("first_Letter");
        first_L.style.color = "blue";
    }
</script>
```