# How to keep the selection mark in UiWebview even after the textview become first responder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

User can select the work and button action --> show textview. When user starts typing "selection" disappears . Is there any way to keep the selection ?

Comment: your question is not clear....?

Comment: once i selected text from webview am showing the textview above that UIWEbView. If user start typing , that selection in that UIWEBView dismisses. Hot to stop that ?

Comment: @RathnaKumaran
Found a solution or workaround ?

Comment: Solution is. Create a span tag around a selection text. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span.  And load the string of the current webview into the file path to make it permanent.