# Angular Place Selected Text inside Bootstrap Element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am an angular beginner and I have been working on this problem for a few days now but I haven't quite solved it.  I am trying to create a directive where when the user highlights some text, a ui-bootstrap tooltip is automatically created around the selection.  I have the following code that almost does what I want.

```
app.directive('selectOnClick', function ($window, $compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('mouseup', function () {    
                if (window.getSelection) {
                    var sel = window.getSelection();
                    var template = '<a href="#" uib-tooltip="hello">'+sel.toString()+'</a>';
                    replaced = element.html().replace(new RegExp(sel.toString(), "g"), template);
                    element.html(replaced);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem with the above code is that it replaces EVERY instance of the selected text with the tooltip - I just want to put the tooltip around the actual text that was selected.

I have seen posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span) that show how to replace selected text with `span` elements in the following way

```
function surroundSelection() {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    span.style.color = "green";

    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't think this method is compatible with ui-bootstrap elements like tooltips.  I am quite stuck on this so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the matching text from the `selection` and going forward from there, the original context is already lost - you got no way to know which `foo` you have selected from if you have multiple in your paragraph.

In order to achieve what you need, you'll need to work on the `selection` itself, so you can pinpoint it for removal and addition of new content.

You can refer to this answer on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6252893/5039495