# split a html tag by its selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to split the tag by two. I have the tag like this

`<span class="ss" custom-attr="kk"> split content here, and have to split </span>`

If I select the content `and have` and click a button, I want to split a tag like this. Even span contains many attributes. I want to split with that attributes.

```
<span class="ss" custom-attr="kk"> split content here, </span>and have <span class="ss" custom-attr="kk">to split </span>
```

i can get the selected text by using `window.getSelection()`.
ex: https://jsfiddle.net/rx5ojfwc/

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span

Comment: I didnt get a idea for splitting tag.@DanielShillcock

Comment: I want a to split tag, not have to insert a new tag. @Skribja

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```js
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Create your tag and replace the content:

```
var myNewTag = '</span>' + getSelectionText() + '<span>';
```

The function is from user Tim Down: [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

Comment: I cannot use this for dynamic content, because the span will class names, styles or any custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML Version

Using a jQuery plugin, you can grab the selection, and perform the replace. It's dynamic so that you don't even need to know if it's a `<span>` tag.

```js
(function($) {
  $.getSelectedText = function() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
      return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
      return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
  };
  $.fn.spanSelectReplace = function() {
    var tag = this.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
    var tStart = '<' + tag + '>';
    var tEnd = '</' + tag + '>';
    var selText = $.getSelectedText();
    return this.replaceWith(tStart + this.html().replace(selText, tEnd + selText + tStart) + tEnd);
  }
})(jQuery);

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('span').spanSelectReplace(); // Perform the jQuery function.
  console.log($('span').parent().html()); // Print the HTML to the console.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Split content here, and have to split</span>
<br />
<button>Split</button>
```

#### Output

```
<span>Split content here, </span>and have<span> to split</span>
```

---

### Old Version — Text Only

Highlight the `"and have "` portion of the text in the text area and hit the <kbd>Split</kbd> button.

The text will be replaced by wrapping the selection in closing-opening `<span>` tags.

```js
function splitText(button) {
  var formEl = document.getElementById('content');
  var selection = getSelection(formEl);
  
  formEl.value = formEl.value.replace(selection, '</span>' + selection + '<span>');
}

function getSelection(field) {
  var start = field.selectionStart;
  var finish = field.selectionEnd;
  
  return field.value.substring(start, finish);
}
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<textarea id="content" rows="5"><span> split content here, and have to split </span></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Split" onClick="splitText(this)" />
```

Comment: I cannot use this for dynamic content, because the span will have class names, styles or any custom attributes

Comment: @Sathish Using a jQuery plugin makes it easier. You just need to manipulate the span by modifying its outer HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that @Mr. Polywhirl

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using replace() very easily.

```
var str = "<span> split content here, and have to split </span>";
var res = str.replace("here,", "here, </span>");
res = res.replace("have ", "have <span>");
```

Check out: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: That was manual selection, not the static string to replace. the selection was my dragging the mouse..

Comment: So, now you know how to search and replace a string. Now you need to research how to make the rest, I'm not going to write the code for you :) Here is a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Comment: I got the selected text, but i want to split the tag, i can able to insert a new tag inside the selection. but cannot split. For that only i want answer.

Comment: @Sathish this is again the case where the answer was submitted before edits, please check the edit history and please don't downvote "innocent answers !! lol.."

Answer (score -1):

You can split() and join() and replace() to achieve this:

Storing the string into a var:

```
var str = "<span> split content here, and have to split </span>";
```

Manuplating the string:

```
str.split(",").join(", </span>").replace("and have", "and have <span>")
```

```js
var str = "<span> split content here, and have to split </span>";
str.split(",").join(", </span>").replace("and have", "and have <span>")
console.log(str);
```

Comment: this is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Its not like that the static content, the content was selecting by manual mouse dragging.

Comment: Guys, please check the edit history, as I think more info was added at the later part of asking the initial question!