# Insert custom tags in a contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I have this:

```html
<input type="button" value="B" onclick="document.execCommand('bold', false, '');" />
<div contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
```

The `document.execCommand` works fine. But what if a want to add a custom tag, like `<customtag></customtag>` surrounding the selected text?

The button need to add the tag to the selected text or eliminate it if it already has it.

Is there a HTML-only solution for this. If not, any pure Javascript solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping a selected text node with span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/wrapping-a-selected-text-node-with-span)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `insertHTML` command:

Basic usage:

```
<input type="button" value="html" onclick="document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<customtag>'+window.getSelection()+'</customtag>');" />
```

To toggle the custom tag on and off, a more complicated logic is needed:

```
<input type="button" value="html" onclick="document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, toggle(window.getSelection());" />

function toggle(txt)
{
    return is_enclosed_within_a_customtag(txt)
         ? strip_custom_tag_off(txt)
         : "<customtag>"+txt+"</customtag>"
    ;   
}
```

### Update

Function `is_enclosed_within_a_customtag` might be implemented, at least, like this:

```
function is_enclosed_within_a_customtag(txt)
{
    return txt.startsWith("<customtag>") && txt.endsWith("</customtag>");
}
```

... and be called passing `window.getSelection().toString()` as parameter.

Comment: Any idea how do we define `is_enclosed_within_a_customtag` and `strip_custom_tag_off`? The `txt` is actually an object so not able to use RegEx?

Comment: When doing `window.getSelection().toString()` it strips off the HTML tag and only gives the text. So `txt.startsWith("<customtag>")` is always false.