# TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a texteditor (div) and there's a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983870/6212957) to format the (selected)text inside it. When I mark a part of the text and chose to make it look like `this` (code snippet) I have to use `&nbsp;` to avoid some bugs and make it user-friendly. However this data is being sent to the server (nodeJS) and it causes a bug where the content splits up into an object and to avoid this issue, I wanted to replace `&nbsp;` with a space before sending it to the server.

What I did was the following

```
// replace &nbsp; by " "
let content = $('.editor').html().replace(/(&nbsp;)/gi, " ");

// replace editor html
$('.editor').html(content);

// print results
console.log("html: ",$('.editor').html());
```

in console it displays what is expected (text : `as <code>dasdasd</code>`):

```
html:  as<span> </span><code>dasdasd</code><span> </span>
```

however on the serverside i got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

then i decided to print the variable which contains the content from editor (which seems fine?):

```
{ posterContent: 'as<span> </span><code>dasdasd</code><span> </span>' }
```

**Question:** how can I replace `&nbsp;` with a space without having to convert html to (string) in order to avoid this error?

Comment: Instead of guessing how to work around a problem, why not include the code that produces the TypeError, indicating in which line it occurs?

Comment: NodeJS does not show where the error occured all I know is which file it is. Do you know of any way to enable some sort of debugging mode in node?

Comment: But you *can* debug the code. Find out where it produces that error. There are many ways to do so.

Comment: Don't be shy, feel free to let me know about those ways

Comment: It is not a matter of shyness. You should take the initiative and look for yourself. A simple search on the internet leads to this: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: Not able to install it, OS: OS X Mojave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you solved the problem, but you might be interested in reading this, because your problem arised from a misunderstood basic concept of web dev which is data encoding.

As far as I understand, you can't pass the string `&nbsp;` to your back-end because it's parsed as an object, so I assume you either used GET or POST's [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) encoding to send request. In simpler terms:

```
// this object
{
  a: 10,
  b: 20
}

// get passed to the server as this string
a=10&b=20
```

Which is fine. That's one way to do. But you have to deal with proper encoding for sending special characters, example:

```
// you have this object:
{
  a: 10,
  b: 'hello&world'
}

// you encode it naively to this
a=10&b=hello&nbsp;world

// the server understands this
{
  a: 10,
  b: 'hello',
  nbsp: ';world'
}
```

The `&` creates the bug, because it's a special character and won't be treater as part of a string. **Even if you find a trick to not use `&nbsp`, or to replace it by a space, you'll think you have solved the problem, but... *almost all unicode characters are special characters and need to be encoded so as to not create bugs*.**

Encode your strings using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), or POST your data with a different encoding (for example, JSON). I'd personally use a function like [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) which does all the job for you and spare you with all the encoding-related issues:

```js
let data = {
  userId: 1,
  id: 1
}

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',{
  method: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: Thank you, master. Lord doge appreciates this answer :D Very helpful it was.