# How to change font style of window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript, html, font-style

I want to know how can I **change the font style** of the selected text, using `window.getSelection()`, after clicking in a **button**.

For example, supose that we have the following phrase:

> Hello world!

If I just select the string `ell` from it and after that, click in a button, it will return (in this case, for example, **bold** type):

> H**ell**o world!

So, how could I do that?
My main problem is: *what **variable type** should I **convert** the `window.getSelection()` to change the **font style***, because it returns a **object**, and if I did `.toString()`, it won't help very much.

Comment: Are you using an `contenteditable` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function surroundSelection() {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        span.style.color = "black";

        if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                range.surroundContents(span);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="surroundSelection()" value="Surround">
    <div contenteditable="true">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to surround the highlighted text into a new node that you add new style to. Check out this answer [How To Wrap / Surround Highlighted Text With An Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/how-to-wrap-surround-highlighted-text-with-an-element)