# How to wrap all selected text into span elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, selection

There are a lot of questions answered how to select text from **one** element. For example, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328718/how-to-wrap-surround-highlighted-text-with-an-element):

```
function surroundSelection() {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    span.style.color = "green";

    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

But how do we do this for multiple tags? For example, if this is the markup

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>consectetur START HERE adipisicing elit.</p>
<p>Eaque et END HERE possimus at minima, illo?</p>
```

If the user selects the the text from the second and third paragraph, how can the be wrapped in their own individual divs

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>consectetur <span>adipisicing elit.</span></p>
<p><span>Eaque et</span> possimus at minima, illo?</p>
```

I hope [this "broken" example](https://jsbin.com/magunemela/edit?html,js,output) helps

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more, don't understand the result you want.

Comment: @tmach say you have 5 paragraphs. You select the last sentence from paragraph 2 and some words from paragraph 3. You want these words to we wrapped into `span` tags. the end result being two span tags, one in 2nd paragraph and one in the third

Comment: Please give an example of what you want after.

Comment: @Imrul.H I'm not sure how: it's something like this extention https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/weava-highlighter-pdf-web/cbnaodkpfinfiipjblikofhlhlcickei?hl=en-GB BUT the screenshot doesn't do justice. The ability to highlight a running sentence from one element to the other!

Comment: @Imrul.H here's what I want https://jsbin.com/magunemela/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @tmach Heres what I want https://jsbin.com/magunemela/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ok, now I understand I will see for a solution.

Comment: You can try with a bind function (mouseup) for the body and inside something like: window.getSelection() and document.selection.createRange(). Not exactly sure how you want this.

Comment: @relidon did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.getSelection** & **window.getSelection.toString()**.

I made a fast example which displays the selected text in a h4 element.

```js
function getSelectedText() {
    let selectedText = document.getElementById('selectedText');
    
    if (window.getSelection) {
        selectedText.innerHTML = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        selectedText.innerHTML = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
 
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>consectetur START HERE adipisicing elit.</p>
<p>Eaque et END HERE possimus at minima, illo?</p>
<input type="button" onclick="getSelectedText()" value="Get Selection">
<h4 id="selectedText"></h4>
```

You can also see the code in action at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tmach/pen/oNNVjPw).

Comment: No,  that's not what I was after. I want them highlighted where they are like this https://jsbin.com/vigawunogi/edit?html