# Clear text selection on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection, gradient

**Annotation:**

The question is based on a [previous question of mine about a color gradient on text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392935/underline-text-with-line-when-selected).

**The problem:**

I have changed the text selection so that the background now displays a gradient. The text can be selected normally (with the gradient), but the selection also remains permanently.

**The question:**

Normally, once the user clicks the mouse, the text is no longer selected. Is it possible to create the same with JavaScript? So that a certain style is deleted / hidden somewhere on the page when the mouse is clicked.

**The current code:**

```js
    textSelected = false

function wrapSelectedText() {       
        var selectedText = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

        var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        /* Styling */
        span.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(120deg, #84fab0 0%, #8fd3f4 100%)";
        span.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        span.style.backgroundSize = "100% 0.2em";
        span.style.backgroundPosition = "0 88%";

        span.appendChild(selectedText);
        selection.insertNode(span);
        textSelected = true;
}

document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
    wrapSelectedText()
}

document.onmousedown = function() {
  if (textSelected == true) {
    // Code for deleting style
    alert("Unselect")
  }
}
```

```css
::selection {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<p>This is an example text.</p>
```

Comment: Almost anything can be done with javascript. But first, please share your code and what you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Yup, added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on this way

```
if (window.getSelection) {
  if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
    window.getSelection().empty();
  } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
} else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
  document.selection.empty();
}
```

Credit : [Clear Text Selection with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript)