# Insert text before and after selection in a contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Is there a way to insert text similar to bbcode before and after the selected text in a contenteditable div? I've seen many answers for textarea, but the code does not work with a contenteditable div. IE support is not needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The approach I'd suggest is:

- Obtain a range from the selection
- Insert a text node at the end of the range
- Insert another text node at the start of the range
- Reselect the original text

The following demo will work in all major browsers except IE <= 8.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8WEru/

Code:

```
function surroundSelection(textBefore, textAfter) {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;

            var startTextNode = document.createTextNode(textBefore);
            var endTextNode = document.createTextNode(textAfter);

            var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
            boundaryRange.collapse(false);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(endTextNode);
            boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
            boundaryRange.collapse(true);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(startTextNode);

            // Reselect the original text
            range.setStartAfter(startTextNode);
            range.setEndBefore(endTextNode);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use an html element if I need to, to show boldness instead of the [b] tag? Like a rich text editor?

Comment: @Flaxbeard: If boldness is more important than controlling precise mark-up, I'd use `document.execCommand("bold", false, null)`. Otherwise, you could adapt [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691294/96100).

Comment: I'd rather not use execcommand as it's uncontrollable cross-browser and only works for some tags. Do I just use createElement("strong"); and set the innerhtml to the selected text? Also, how would I add a style/class/id to this element?

Comment: I started working on this project again and I'm wondering how I can insert an html element instead of text without using execcommand.

Comment: @Flaxbeard: Just create elements rather text nodes for `startTextNode` and `endTextNode`.

Comment: is there not a more concise/easier way to do this?

Comment: @Anthony: No. There are shortcuts you could take if, say, you knew the selection was completely contained within a single text node but for the general case there is no specific native API for this particular task so you have to use what there is.

Comment: How would one get this to work on highlighted text *inside* a textarea element?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand from your comments the new goal, you have a selection and want to surround it by an element. Then the **surroundContents** method of range should work:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var strong = document.createElement('strong');
range.surroundContents(strong);
```

Comment: Note, this only works for adding elements - not text nodes.